# Finding $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+2x}-1}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Good morning everyone, first time posting here.

> For my calculus class, we are asked to find  $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+2x}-1}{x}$$

We are given the hint that $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$

I have tried several step by step online solvers, but they all use derivatives and something called the 'hospital' rule, which we haven't learned yet.

So in conclusion, if someone could set me on a path to solving this that uses the hint I included, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: $$\frac{(1+2x)^{1/3}-1}x \cdot \frac{(1+2x)^{2/3}+(1+2x)^{1/3}+1}{(1+2x)^{2/3}+(1+2x)^{1/3}+1}$$

Comment: You can try this pattern : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789907/lim-limits-x-to-1-frac-sqrtx3-2x-1-without-lhopitals-rule/1789945#1789945

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one puts $a=\sqrt[3]{1+2x}$, $b=1$ in
$$
a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)
$$ one gets
$$
\sqrt[3]{1+2x}-1=\frac{(1+2x)-1}{(1+2x)^{2/3}+\sqrt[3]{1+2x}+1}=\frac{2x}{(1+2x)^{2/3}+\sqrt[3]{1+2x}+1}
$$ giving, as $x \to0$,

> $$
> \frac{\sqrt[3]{1+2x}-1}{x}=\frac2{(1+2x)^{2/3}+\sqrt[3]{1+2x}+1}
> $$

then one may conclude easily.