# What am I doing wrong in calculating the following limit?

Tags: limits, radicals

$$\lim_{x\to-2} \frac{x+2}{\sqrt{6+x}-2}=\lim_{x\to-2} \frac{1+2/x}{\sqrt{(6/x^2)+(1/x)}-2/x^2}$$ Dividing numerator and denominator by $x \neq0$

$$\frac{1+2/-2}{\sqrt{(6/4)+(1/-2)}-2/4}=\frac{0}{1/2}=0$$ but the limit is $4$ according to Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: Why do you have $2/x^2$ in denominator?

Comment: Standard trick for this kind of limit: multiply numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{6+x}+2$.

Comment: Spotted my mistake thank you.

Comment: Try http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789907/lim-limits-x-to-1-frac-sqrtx3-2x-1-without-lhopitals-rule/1789945#1789945

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You say you divide by $x$, but that's not what you do in the denominator; it would be:

$$\lim_{x\to-2} \frac{x+2}{\sqrt{6+x}-2}
=\lim_{x\to-2} \frac{1+\tfrac{2}{x}}{\tfrac{\sqrt{6+x}}{x}-\tfrac{2}{x}} =\lim_{x\to-2} \frac{1+\tfrac{2}{x}}{-\sqrt{\tfrac{6}{x^2}+\tfrac{1}{x}}-\tfrac{2}{x}} $$

A better approach:
$$\begin{array}{rl}
\displaystyle \lim_{x\to-2} \frac{x+2}{\sqrt{6+x}-2}
& \displaystyle = \lim_{x\to-2} \frac{\left(x+2\right)\color{blue}{\left(\sqrt{6+x}+2\right)}}{\left(\sqrt{6+x}-2\right)\color{blue}{\left(\sqrt{6+x}+2\right)}} \\[7pt]
& \displaystyle = \lim_{x\to-2} \frac{\left(x+2\right)\left(\sqrt{6+x}+2\right)}{x+2} \\[7pt]
& \displaystyle = \lim_{x\to-2} \left(\sqrt{6+x}+2\right) \\
& = 4
\end{array}$$

Comment: Its been a while since I did limits so forgive me if this is a silly question but when taking the square root in the final step is there a reason we take the positive root and discard the negative root?

Comment: That's a matter of definition, $x^2 = a$ has two solutions (for $a>0$) but the notation $\sqrt{a}$ is reserved for the positive one; so $\sqrt{4} = 2$.

Comment: Ah, cool. That makes sense. Thanks. :)

Comment: In fact, if you plug $x=-2$ into the denominator of your last expression in the first formula, you get $\sqrt{\tfrac6{x^2}+\tfrac1x}-\tfrac2x=1+1=2$. So this would lead to limit equal to zero.
The correct version would be, in my opinion, $-\sqrt{\tfrac6{x^2}+\tfrac1x}-\tfrac2x$ in the denominator. Notice that this leads to the indeterminate form $\tfrac00$, as expected. (We are using that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=-x$ for $x<0$. Since we are interested in the values close to $-2$, it suffices to work with negative $x$.)

Comment: You are correct, there was a minus sign missing before the square root - thanks.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak, I didn't understand, why is there a negative sign there?

Comment: @MrReality You have $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$. So for $x<0$ this gives you $x=-|x|=-\sqrt{x^2}$. This is explained in the comment above.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak Yes, I saw the earlier comment. I understand the reason for a minus sign in the examole you gave now but in your answer the term inside the square root is not $x^2$ here, it is $\sqrt{\tfrac6{x^2}+\tfrac1x}$. So why is a minus sign there?

Comment: @MrReality Maybe this is what you're after: $\frac{\sqrt{6+x}}{x}= \frac{\sqrt{6+x}}{-\sqrt{x^2}}= -\frac{\sqrt{6+x}}{\sqrt{x^2}}= -\sqrt{\frac{6+x}{x^2}}$. In any case, we're leaving too many irrelevant comments here and additionally each of the adds ping to the answerer. So perhaps it would be better to [continue in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2017/10/26) if further comments are needed.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak, thanks that explained it!

Answer (score 6):

One may set $u=x+2$, then, as $x \to -2$, we have $u \to 0$, giving
$$
\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{6+x}-2}=\frac{u}{\sqrt{u+4}-2}\times\frac{\sqrt{u+4}+2}{\sqrt{u+4}+2}=\sqrt{u+4}+2 \to 4.
$$

Comment: **;|** quite fast

Answer (score 3):

You can apply L'Hospital rule, i.e differentiating numerator and denominator functions with respect to $x$,

$$2\sqrt{x + 6} = 2 \sqrt{-2 + 6} = 4$$